# Deriving the correct unit of force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, unit-conversion

Take a look of the Newtonian gravity equation below:
$$\text{gravitational force} = \frac{GMm}{r^2}$$
$GM$ of earth is $398600.4418\ \mathrm{km^3 s^{-2}}$. Let $m = 1000\ \mathrm{kg}$, and $r = 6378\ \mathrm{km}$. Using these values in the equation we get:
$$F_g=\frac{398600.4418\times 1000}{6378^2}=9.79870641977297\hspace{1em}???$$

What is the unit of the force computed by the above equation using the provided values? Is it kilonewtons or just newtons?

The reason why I am confusing between kilonewtons and newtons is because I am using $GM = 398600.4418\ \mathrm{km^3 s^{-2}}$ instead of $3.986004418 \times 10^{14}\ \mathrm{m^3 s^{−2}}$ along with **r in kilometers**.

Comment: I would highly recommend using scientific notation and give only relevant digits. If you plug in values in your equation allways keep the units. You calculate with physical quantities not with bare numbers. If you do that questions like that will not come up. The value you calculated for $F_g$ is correct with the unit kilonewton.

Comment: It's best to only use the standard SI units (kg, m, s), and use scientific notation to deal with the large and small numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: @matrp was faster but here bassicaly the same computation:
Lets put in all the values with their units because that the only proper way to compute with physical quantites:
\begin{align} F_g & = \frac{G M m}{r^2}\\\\ &=\frac{6.67\times10^{^-11}\mathrm{m}^{3}\mathrm{kg}^{^-1}\mathrm{s}^{-2}* 5.972\times10^{24}~\mathrm{kg}* 1000~ \mathrm{kg}}{(6378~\mathrm{km})^2} \\\\ & = 9.7981\times10^9 \mathrm{kg}~\mathrm{m}^{3}\mathrm{s}^{-2}~\mathrm{km}^{^-2}\\\\ & =9.7981\times10^3~\mathrm{kg}~\mathrm{m}~\mathrm{s}^{-2}=9.7981\times10^3~\mathrm{N}=9.7981~\mathrm{kN} \end{align}

Comment: So definitely 9.7981 kN / 1000 kg will yield 0.0097981 km/s^2 ... right?

Comment: @Nadeem Jamali Yes, that is the acceleration of the body. But it's better to use SI base units. Then you will get $0.0097981 km/s^2=9.7981 m/s^2$.

Comment: You can use the units you want but keep them when calculating. Some people like to convert everything in SI before plugging it in but if you keep your units then it does not matter at all. Just keep your units and then you can convert them as you please. Using scientific notation and relevant digits helps also.

Comment: @M.J.Steil Although SI Units are the most suitable units for the most of the calculation purposes. But in some cases we are left with no choice. For example, I am simulating solar system. Hence using meter as the unit of distance for the distance from Sun to Earth is not suitable. Here eventually we have to use AU or at least kilometers.

Comment: @Nadeem Jamali I'm developing a gravity simulator too, and I still use meters for calculations, but it doesn't really matter which unit you choose for numerical operations if you use floating points. I convert distances to other units only when displaying them.

Comment: Thats really a good food for thought...

Answer (score 1):

Try writing the unities in the equation:

\begin{equation}
F_g = \frac{(398600.4418 \, km^3 s^{-2})\cdot 10^3 kg}{(6378 \,km)^2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
F_g = 9.7987 \frac{km^3 \cdot kg}{s^2 \, km^2} =  9.7987 \frac{km \cdot kg}{s^2 }
\end{equation}

Since Newton unit is $\frac{m \cdot kg}{s^2}$, you have to remeber that $1000$ meters is equal to $1$ kilometer, so

\begin{equation}
F_g =  9.7987 \frac{km \cdot kg}{s^2 } \times \left( \frac{1000 \, m}{1 \, km} \right)
\end{equation}

is the same as multiplying the equation by $1$, just changing the unities,  so:
\begin{equation}
F_g =  9.7987 \times 10^3 N
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

- Using $km$ instead of $m$ makes the number 1000 times smaller. ($2500 \;m$ is $2.5\;km$.)
- Using $km^2$ instead of $m^2$ makes the number $1000^2$ times smaller.
- Using $km^3$ instead of $m^3$ makes the number $1000^3$ smaller.

So, the numerator is $1000^3$ times smaller (making the whole number $1000^3$ times smaller), and the denominator is $1000^2$ times smaller (making the whole number $1000^2$ times **bigger**).

This results in the number being just $1000^{3-2}=1000^1$ times smaller. So add *kilo* to adjust it (making the value $10^3$ times bigger again), so that the end result is in *kilonewton*, $kN$, and the number fits.

Comment: Actually both $GM$ and $r$ are given in kilometers, so the result is only $10^9/10^6=10^3$ smaller. So the correct unit is $kN$.

Comment: @Ale Thats why I could grab the answer by @Steeven! He confused me more. But still I am not sure!

Comment: @Ale Oh, sorry, my mistake. I have fixed the answer now. Thanks. I apologise, if this was confusing at first, Nadeem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is definitely is kiloNewtons. The end units that you are left with are km*kg*(s^-2). The regular Newton is m*kg*(s^-2). This means that your answer is 1000 times greater than a Newton.

If you want a check just put the force through Newton's second law. Since your answer is close to the accepted value of the acceleration near the surface of Earth and you are using an object that is 1000kg. Your answer must have a factor of 1000 hidden somewhere for you to get the right answer.